# Django admin dynamically add to list_display and create ModelAdmin methods

Tags: django

I'd like to dynamically include some extra fields in the `list_display` of the admin for one of my models. I plan on overriding `get_list_display` to append [a string representing a `ModelAdmin` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) but how can I dynamically create the `ModelAdmin` methods?

In the example below if `get_list_display` returns `[..., 'module_1', 'module_2']` that means I need methods for `module_1` and `module_2` as they're not model fields.

```
class Type(models.Model):
    ...
    modules = models.ManyToManyField(Module)

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type)

class UserModuleRecord(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy=True

@admin.register(UserModuleRecord)
class UserModuleRecordAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return (
            super().get_queryset(request)
            .annotate_the_additional_list_display_values()
        )

    def get_list_display(self, request):
        list_display = super().get_list_display(request)
        modules = Module.objects.all()
        for module in modules:
            list_display.append('module_%s' % module.id)
        return list_display
```

Additionally is it possible to create something similar to how `get_FOO_display` works so there's only one admin method required?

**UPDATE**

I think I'm close with the following but am getting an error `TypeError: 'partialmethod' object is not callable`

```
from functools import partialmethod

def get_list_display(self, request):
    list_display = super().get_list_display(request)
    modules = Module.objects.all()
    for module in modules:
        attr_name = 'module_%s' % module.id
        list_display.append(attr_name)

        if not hasattr(self, attr_name):
            setattr(self, attr_name, partialmethod(
                self._module_id, field=attr_name
            ))
    return list_display

def _module_id(self, obj, field=''):
    return getattr(obj, field, '')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following makes use of `functools.partial` to return a partial object which behaves like a function when called - similar to Django's [`get_FOO_display()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display).

```
@admin.register(models.EmployeeTrainingRecord)
class EmployeeTrainingRecordAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ('email',)
    list_display = [
        'id',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
    ]

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return (
            super().get_queryset(request)
            .annotate_training_dates()
        )

    def get_list_display(self, request):
        list_display = super().get_list_display(request)
        training_modules = models.Training.objects.all()
        for training in training_modules:
            attr_name = 'training_%s' % training.id

            if not hasattr(self, attr_name):
                list_display.append(attr_name)
                func = partial(self._get_training_id, field=attr_name)
                func.short_description = training.name
                setattr(self, attr_name, func)
        return list_display

    @staticmethod
    def _get_training_id(obj, field=''):
        return getattr(obj, field, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly I think you're half way to the answer already.

As you know, to add anything custom to the `list_display` fields that isn't already a model field you need to implement it with a method on your `ModelAdmin` instance.

You can dynamically create field methods on the ModelAdmin instance using python's `setattr` and a wrapped function and doing it when the instance is initialised.

For example you could create a series of methods on your instance this way:

```
def make_dynamic_field(*args):
    def dynamic_field(self, obj):
        i = args[0]
        return f'{obj.first_name} {i}'
    return dynamic_field

@admin.register(UserModuleRecord)
class UserModuleRecordAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_display = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'foo_0', 'foo_1']

    def __init__(self, model, admin_site):
        super().__init__(model, admin_site)

        for i in range(2):
            setattr(self, f'foo_{i}', make_dynamic_field(i))
```

I have used the index variable `i` as an example but you could potentially inject any variable into your dynamic field method this way.